# Use external button to upload image/videos in froala editor

Tags: jquery, css, froala

I am using Inline froala editor 2.4.0 where I hid the default inline toolbar and quickinsert toolbar because of the requirements.I would like to assign an external button for image / video / file upload feature.Is there any way we can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can place a hidden file upload button on page and bind its event to your custom button like this.

`$.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('uploadVideo', { NAME: 'file-video-o' });
        $.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('uploadVideo', {
            title: 'Upload Video File',
            focus: false,
            undo: true,
            refreshAfterCallback: false,
            callback: function (e, editor) {
                $('[data-cmd="' + e + '"].fr-blink').closest('.fr-box').nextAll('textarea:first').addClass('activeFrbox');
                $('#uploadVideo').click();
            }
        });`

After this you can make a click event for file upload and call whatever you want on it.

```
$(document).off('change', '#uploadVideo');
    $(document).on('change', '#uploadVideo', function () {
        if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $('#loadingWithBG').show();
            setTimeout(function () {
                UploadVideoFile();
            }, 100);
        } else {
            $('.activeFrbox').removeClass('activeFrbox');
        }
    });
```

This is how I have added and worked with external buttons.

Comment: Thanks I will try it.

Comment: Hello - I have been trying to do this but it doesn't seem to be working.  I can't figure out how to programmatically select any of the froala toolbar buttons.  The button id for insert image is 'insertImage-1' and I am trying $('#insertImage-1').click() but it is not working.  Any ideas what I'm missing?  Thank you.